# Why isn't the parent adjusting it's width to content?

Tags: html, css

I might just be really tired but I can't for the life of me figure out why `display: inline-block` isn't working to make the parent's width adjust to the size of it's contents. I've tried searching for other solutions but every resource I've found says adding `inline-block` to the parent should do the trick.

In the example below, I am trying to make the blue square only extend to the edge of the green square, and then ultimately center the contents via `margin: 0 auto;`:

```css
#intro {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
.slide-txt {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: lime;
}
.slide-box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section id="intro" class="image-slider">  
  <div class="container" id="intro-slide">  
    <div class="slide-box">    
      <img src="http://www.jkoffset.com/assets/images/Packaging1.jpg" alt="same-box-slide" width="150px">

      <div class="slide-txt">
        <h1 class="title">Headline <span>Goes Here</span></h1>
        <div class="caption"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
          <a class="btn" href="#"> 
            Learn More
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eam0mk47/

Comment: don't use width %  in this class .slide-txt ...use px instead

Comment: That did it. Thank you. If you submit it as the answer I will mark it as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `width:30%;` in the div child (**.slide-txt**) will make the parent div expand to fill the other 70%, so to avoid that and make it adjust according to content you need to use px instead of % in the div child.

Comment: Cheers, i'm glad it helped :) !!

Answer (score 0):

In that red #intro is a div with the class .container ... this element has padding left and right via bootstrap.

Just remove that padding:
https://jsfiddle.net/eam0mk47/1/

```
#intro .container {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Or don't use that class there.

Comment: The blue box still takes up the entire width instead of only being as wide as it's children (stopping just after the lime box).